# Html.ActionLink to call an action from a different controller that's in a different folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, actionlink

I've got a simple view that creates a link if a login is successful and is located under /Login:

```
<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Add a new Organization", "AddOrganization", 
           "/Setup/AddOrganizationController", new { id = Session["ID"] }, null)
</div>
```

After reading other similiar problems, I tried it adding the null after, as well as a few other overloads, but I can't get the link to work right.  When I click the link, it takes me to

```
http://setup/AddOrganizationController/AddOrganization
```

Which is leaving out the localhost part that needs to be there.  Without the null at the end, it tries to send me to

```
/Login/AddOrganization
```

All I want is a link that will run an action within the AddOrganizationController controller which is under /Setup directory.  The link should also pass the session id to the controller as an argument.  How can I do this?

Comment: I really don't know what that is, so I guess I'm not.

Comment: I can't really answer your question, don't even know the structure of your project but I guess it's worth you take a look at them. Maybe this answer helps you http://stackoverflow.com/a/6555971/1179061

Answer (score 6):

If it's in the same `Area` then you can just do:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add a new Organization", "AddOrganization", "Organizations", new { id = Session["ID"] })
```

where "Organizations" is the controller name.

Otherwise, if it's in another area you would do something like

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add a new Organization", "AddOrganization", "Organizations", new { area = "areaName", id = Session["ID"] }, null)
```